# What are all the potentially possible documents do we need for aufenthaltstitel?

Tags: germany

I can't find a definitive list online , and it seems it can potentially vary from state to state.

To my research I find we need the following docs at very east:

1. Proof of employement/ student
2. Funds
3. Insurance
4. Blocked account
5. Anmeldung beim Buergerservice
6. Passport photos

I am concernced certain Auslandbehoere may ask more. I read somewhere that birth certificate maybe required. Could someone confirm?

Comment: Ultimately it depends on your specific circumstances and the specific requirements of the specific Ausländerbehörde you apply to. Talk to them. They'll tell you definitively.